# Do we need two (g430/gns430) tags for the same thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Do we really need both the [g430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g430) and [gns430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gns430) tags?

Currently they have been edited to have

1. the same wiki [g430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/g430/info) and [gns430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/gns430/info)
2. they are in the review queue to have the same wiki excerpt:

   > Questions related to the Garmin 430

Comment: My bad. I meant to just make the GNS430 tag.

Comment: Could you edit the title to be more specific about the tags involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [g430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g430) tag?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[gns430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gns430) should be kept and [g430](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g430) should be made a synonym.